# How to receive a wav audio file using HTTP POST in Perl and play it in Asterisk AGI

Tags: perl, audio, asterisk

I am using [IBM Watson TTS](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/?curl#) for Text-to-Speech functionality. 
I am able to get the audio file using Postman's [Send and Download](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/responses) functionality. But, how I am supposed to do that in Perl.
I am completely new to Perl. 
The reason I am using Perl to do it, is that I need to implement TTS in Asterisk AGI.

**Edit**: I am able to save the file. But, unable to play it in Asterisk.

I am using following code snippet for the POST request and playing audio:

```
....
my $uaresponse = $ua->post(
    "$url",
    Content_Type => "application/json",
    Accept => "audio/wav",
    Authorization => "Basic OWFmMjhhYmItMWFmMi00ZjU0LWE1YTAtNTJhNGUxNjRjNGQ1OnlkYWgwN3BRdEJMVA==",
    Content => $json_text,
);

if(!$uaresponse->is_success){
    print "Failed request to IBM \n";
} else{
    print "Successful with IBM \n";

    ($fh, $tmpname) = tempfile("ggl_XXXXXXXX", DIR => $tmpdir, UNLINK => 1);

    $tmpname = $uaresponse->content;

# my approach is wrong somewhere here...??

    #print "$tmpname\n";


#           open(my $out, '>:wav', "$tmpname.wav") or die "unable to open $!";
#           print $out pack('a*', $ua_response2->content);

   # Playback and save file in cache #
    $res = playback($tmpname, $intkey);
    die if ($res < 0);
    last if ($res > 0);

}

 sub checkresponse {
my $input = <STDIN>;
my @values;

chomp $input;
if ($input =~ /^200 result=(-?\d+)\s?(.*)$/) {
    @values = ("$1", "$2");
} else {
    $input .= <STDIN> if ($input =~ /^520-Invalid/);
    warn "$name Unexpected result: $input\n";
    @values = (-1, -1);
}
return @values;
}

sub playback {
my ($file, $keys) = @_;
my @response;

print "STREAM FILE $file \"$keys\"\n";
@response = checkresponse();
if ($response[0] >= 32 && chr($response[0]) =~ /[\w*#]/) {
    console_log("Got digit chr($response[0])") if ($debug);
    print "SET EXTENSION ", chr($response[0]), "\n";
    checkresponse();
    print "SET PRIORITY 1\n";
    checkresponse();
} elsif ($response[0] == -1) {
    console_log("Failed to play $file.");
}
return $response[0];
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using eAGI to stream audio directly from the script? https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_EAGI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) for your `$ua` and [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp) for the `tempfile` function.

[`tempfile`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp#tempfile) returns a filehandle and a *filename*. `$uaresponse` is an [HTTP::Response](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Response) object, and its [method `content`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response#r-content) returns the undecoded, raw body of the HTTP response.

You are assigning that body (which is probably the full wave file) to the variable that holds the filename of the temporary file. You never write the content to the file. You are trying to do that in your commented out code, but since you had already overwritten the filename it would not have worked.

You can use the `$fh` that `tempfile` gives you directly. Since wave is binary data, it makes sense to set `binmode` on `$fh`. You can then directly write into it.

```
if(!$uaresponse->is_success){
    print "Failed request to IBM \n";
} else{
    print "Successful with IBM \n";

    my ($fh, $tmpname) = tempfile("ggl_XXXXXXXX.wav", DIR => $tmpdir, UNLINK => 1);
    binmode $fh;
    print $fh $uaresponse->content; # or with pack if you want
}
```

That should be it. There is no `:wav` encoding in Perl, so that part of the code you tried would not have worked anyway.

Note that in your call to `tempfile` you set the `UNLINK => 1` option, which means that the temporary file will be automatically deleted once your program ends. It seems like that's not what you want. It looks like you want to keep that file. Maybe File::Temp is not the right approach in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: The other problem which I am facing is the file is being saved as "ggl_XXXX" without the extension .wav, so when I am trying to play the file using
print "STREAM FILE $file \"$keys\"\n";
I am getting "failed to play" error.

Comment: @DhawanGupta well, you haven't told it to use the right extension. But I don't see why that would matter unless it's on Windows.

Comment: How can I tell it to use the right extension? 
P.S. I have added the code for playing the file.

Comment: It's CentOS 6 based [AsteriskNOW](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Installing+AsteriskNOW)

Comment: @DhawanGupta change the filename when you create the file. But I don't know anything about Asterisk, so I cannot really help you. I told you what was wrong with your code, but I cannot solve your task for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is issues in order of most liked first.

1) File must have **EXACT** format: **wav, pcm 8khz, 16 bit, mono**. Any other format will be ignored. If you have other format, you have use sox or other tool for change format first. If you **UNSURE** about format, you should use sox or other tool to be sure format is supported one.

2) Filename you send to asterisk should be without .wav extension at end. User Asterisk::AGI module, no need rewrite agi interaction from scratch.

3) file must have permission for read by asterisk user

4) Dir where file located must have permission for open/read by asterisk user

Comment: I think the 3rd and 4th might be the reason. I used "chmod 777" for file permission. Is it correct way to do that? What must be the right way?

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided by @arheops and @simbabque surely helped.

The mischievious error which was hindering the normal functioning of my program was the print statement:

```
print "Successful with IBM \n";
```

I learned it the hard way that print statements are executed on the Asterisk CLI so, above one was giving an error (510 Invalid or Unknown Command) which I was overlooking. Once I commented out the print response, it was working fine.

However, if you feel like using print, correct way should be:

```
print "VERBOSE \" Successful with IBM \" \n";
```